# Another question on De Franchis's theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an algebraic curve defined over the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$ of genus $g > 1$. A theorem of De Franchis states that there exist only finitely many (isomorphism classes of) curves $Y$ defined over $\mathbb{C}$ with genus exceeding one such that there exists a non-constant map $f: X \rightarrow Y$. For a given curve $X$, put $S(X)$ for the set of (isomorphism classes of) curves $Y$ with genus exceeding one such that there exists a non-constant map $f: X \rightarrow Y$.

Now suppose that for two curves $X_1, X_2$ with equal genus $g > 1$, that $S(X_1) = S(X_2)$. What can be said about $X_1, X_2$?

Comment: A very general curve $X/\mathbb{C}$ (eg with simple Jacobian) only maps to $\mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: You require the maps $f$ to be holomorphic, right?

Comment: $X$ is the only curve in $S(X)$ of genus $g$, so if $X_1,X_2$ have the same genus $g$ and $S(X_1)=S(X_2)$ then $X_1=X_2$.

Comment: If, as in Felipe's comment X is in S(X), you lose.  If you require S(X) to only include curves of lower genus, then consider Y to be any curve g>1, and let X be, say a ramified double cover.  Lots of those.